# Fake referrer not working

Tags: php, curl, referrer

I'm using this code for to fake the referrer of a user when he clicks on my link, to make it look like he's coming from Facebook:

```
 <?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://bit.ly/randomurl');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.facebook.com/')
$html = curl_exec($ch);   
?>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, as the referrer I see is the url of the code above.
How can I fix it? And I really could appreciate some help with the coding as I'm not a coder.

Comment: How are you examining the referer?

Comment: @Quentin: I'm using Live HTTP Headers from Mozilla.

Comment: @Mischa: I know, but I need bit.ly to get the referrer as the URL of my choice.

Comment: You cannot examine what Referer bit.ly is receiving, as you don't have access to their servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using Live HTTP Headers from Mozilla

You are examining the headers sent by Firefox, but the referer header you are setting manually is being sent by PHP/cURL. That is a different HTTP client and a different set of HTTP requests.

1. Firefox will request your PHP program (and send normal referer headers to it).
2. Your PHP program will request `http://bit.ly/randomurl` (and send the referer header you manually specify to it).
3. `http://bit.ly/randomurl` will respond to your PHP program.
4. Your PHP program will respond to Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the clear up! So that means that the fake referrer is working, right?